# Bayesian Linear regression for non-gaussian distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution, bayesian, pymc3

Which distribution should be considered for non-gaussian distribution while building Bayesian Linear regression. I am trying to build this model using Pymc3 library but since I have just started to learn Bayesian modeling and Pymc3 library so it would be really helpful for me if someone can help and guide me regarding this. Thank you.

Comment: This heavily depends on the distribution you assume your target variable has, conditional on its covariates. For example, if you are working with count data (y>0y>0), then a standard choice would be a Poisson distribution or maybe a Negative Binomial distribution. If you provide more information, I could be more specific about which distributions are commonly used.